# web api asp core :The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-2.1

i need to create a web service for angular 6 . i use the web api in asp core 2.1 ...

when i create this action for edit :

```
        [HttpGet("{id}")]
    [Route("GetRoleById")]
    public async Task<Role> GetRoleById(int id)
    {
        return await _roleManag.FindByIdAsync(id);
    }
```

it not enter in action and it show me error in Inspecter Element :

> The character encoding of the plain text document was not declared. The document will render with garbled text in some browser configurations if the document contains characters from outside the US-ASCII range. The character encoding of the file needs to be declared in the transfer protocol or file needs to use a byte order mark as an encoding signature.

i enter this url in webbrowser: `https://localhost:44390/api/role/GetRoleById/2`

whats the problem ? how cam i solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have wrong route filters: `HttpGet` and `Route` has same functionality. Just change your code to:

```
[HttpGet("GetRoleById/{id}")]
public async Task<Role> GetRoleById(int id)
{
    return await _roleManag.FindByIdAsync(id);
}
```